# Is there a fast method to calculate the nearest point in a data set under a point-depending distance function

Tags: distance, nearest-neighbor

I am searching for a (fast) way to calculate the nearest point y in a dataset to a given point x under a (x,y)-depending distance function.

My distance function has the form: d(x,y) = 1/f(x,y) * |||x-y||^2, where ||x|| denotes the standard Euclidean-norm. The function f(x,y) fulfills all necessary properties such that d(x,y) is a distance measurement i.e. positive, symmetric,...

For a "normal" distance function I could to some transformation on the data itself and use some k-nearest neighbor approaches. But for this case I could not find something useful. Does anyone have an idea?

Right now, I am using Julia for the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use most standard spacial indexes (kd-tree, r-tree, quadtree, and their derivatives) as long as d(x,y) is "convex".

With "convex" I mean that a curve of equidistant points around P is convex. E.g. for Euclidean this is a circle, for Manhatten/Taxi distance it is a square.

This is required because these indexes usually partition the data into squares, rectangles or half-spaces (kd-tree), so they rely on calculating the minimum distance to a group of points by calculating the distance to the corner or sides of a bounding rectangle. As long as your distance function is convex (or at least not concave) then any index of these indexes should work.